# How to append a record in a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have tried to append a record on the next line in the file using the following code(please note that the file has been created already). But, it does not insert any records at all. The file remains empty.

```
with open(utmppath+'/'+tmpfile, "a") as myfile:
   myfile.write(record+'\n')
   myfile.close()
```

Any suggestion would be great. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the proper path? Try running it with the explicit path replacing `utmppath+'/'+tmpfile`.  I ran a similar example and I had no problems getting it to add the record.

Answer (score 1):

Check additionally if you set your path correctly:

```
import os

path = utmppath+'/'+tmpfile
assert os.path.isfile(path), path
```

The assertion checks if the file exists and raises an `AssertionError` if you used a wrong path. Additionally the used path is included in the error message thanks to the variable
after the comma.

Additionally I recommend you to join files with the help of `os.path.join` and `os.path.abspath`. `os.path.join` concatenates path strings correctly for you and `os.path.abspath` creates an absolute path.

```
path = os.path.join(utmppath, tmpfile)
```

Let's say the wished file is in the same directory like your script and called `your_output.txt` - you can use this:

```
path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'your_output.txt'))
```

By the way, `__file__` gives you the name of your script file.

Comment: hello all, thanks for your reply..my bad...I just realized i was modifying another file :( . Thanks!

Comment: @JoieTamayo: Great that you solved your problem. Hopefully my post helped you in it or to get to know some Python features. If you want to thank other users please use the possibility to upvote and/or accept answers. For more details see many posts on metaexchange, for instance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109956/is-it-important-to-say-thanks-after-getting-correct-answer